# Connectedness problem on the 2-sphere

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $K \subset L \subset S^2$, where $S^2$ is the 2-sphere and $K$ and $L$ are compact subsets with empty interior and $L$ is connected (I don't think all of those are relevant hypotheses though, but well).

Suppose $S^2 - L$ is connected. Is it true then that $S^2-K$ is connected as well ?

Comment: $K \subset L$?  I'm not sure, but I would think whether or not $K$ is a subset of $L$ or just $S^2$, it does not need to be connected.

Comment: do you have a counterexample ?

Comment: If the two subsets have empty interior then they are a boundary set (in this case a 1D curve).  Since $S^2 - L$ is connected, $L$ must _not_ divide the region.  This means that $1$) $L$ is not a closed curved and $2$) at _most_ only one endpoint of $L$ lies on the boundary of $S^2$.  If $K$ is a subset of $L$, then $S^2 - K$ must be connected--the only way for it _not_ to be is if $K$ was a closed curve or ended on two distinct boundary points of $S^2$.  On the other hand, if $L$ and $K$ did _not_ have empty interiors, then $S^2 - K$ might not be connected.

Comment: Hint: $$S^2-L \subset S^2-K \subset \overline{S^2-L} = S^2.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer could you please elaborate a little ? I still don't see it...

Comment: @Jared what do you mean by the boundary of $S^2$ ? also what you said corresponds more or less to my intuition of why it should be true, but $L$ may still be fairly horrible, so it's not really a proof...

Comment: Generally, if $E$ is connected, and $E \subset F \subset \overline{E}$, then ...

Comment: oh right. then $F$ is connected, as can be seen by say the continuous functions with values in $\{0,1\}$ caracterization of connectedness ?

Comment: Right. Note that all we need is that $S^2-L$ is connected and dense in $S^2-K$.

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* a formal proof, but I would think you could justify these statements formally to get one.

Since $L$ and $K$ have empty interiors, they must be curves.  There are only two ways for $S^2 - L$ to *not* be connected:

[image]

Either $1$) the curve (or set) $L$ begins and ends on a boundary of $S^2$ or $2$) $L$ is a closed curve.  Now $S^2 - L$ will not be connected because it is the union of two disjoint open sets.

Since $K$ is a subset of $L$, if $L$ does not form a closed curve *and* does not connect two boundary points of $S^2$, then neither can $K$, therefore $S^2 - K$ must also be connected.

On the other hand, if it had not stated that $L$ and $K$ had empty interiors, then this would not necessarily be the case:

[image]

Comment: here $S^2$ is the sphere of dimension 2 (that can be embedded into R^3) not the disk in the plane...

Comment: so there is no boundary of $S^2$, we look at it as a topological space in its own right. besides, as I mentionned, $L$ can be very complicated : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrite_(mathematics) for example

Comment: Since there's no boundary, I would think for $S^2 - L$ to be disconnected, $L$ would have to be a closed curve or, really, consist of at least one connected component that is a closed curve.  My counterexample of $L$ and $K$ with non-empty interiors should still be valid (even on the surface of a 3-sphere).

Comment: OK, but it's still not a proof. Daniel Fischer however gave an argument